# Python - add key-value pair to dictionary in array

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

Question is in title. I can't make it work:

```
>>> data = [{}] * 2
>>> data[1].update({3:4})
>>> data
[{3: 4}, {3: 4}]
```

key-value pair adds to all elements of array. I expected to receive that:

```
[{}, {3: 4}]
```

Comment: whats the intention of doing [{}]*2, since dicts are mutable ,you are creating a reference of same dict twice, so whatever changes you make to first dict will be reflected in the second...

Comment: Unless, I'm missing something, what about an simple assignment? `data[1] = {3: 4}`
    In [33]: data
    Out[33]: [{}, {3: 4}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that

```
data = [{}] * 2
```

Creates a list that has the same dictionary in it twice.

To illustrate this, let's look at `id(data[0])` and `id(data[1])`:

```
>>> data = [{}] * 2
>>> data
[{}, {}]
>>> id(data[0])
4490760552
>>> id(data[1])
4490760552
```

Note that id(data[0]) and id(data[1]) are the same because both entries in the list refer to the same object

What you probably want is

```
>>> d2 = [{} for i in range(2)]
>>> d2[0][4] = 'a'
>>> d2
[{4: 'a'}, {}]
```

Comment: I edited your answer to exemplify , via `id()` function, the fact the `[{}] * 2` points to the same object. Hope you are ok with it!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you added the same dictionary twice to your list.

The trouble is already in your first statement:

> data = [{}] * 2

This creates a list with two times the same entry. When you update one of those, the update will be visible in both entries of the list.

Try this:

```
data = [ {} for i in range(2) ]
```

When you now do your update, you will get your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
data = [{}] * 2
data[1].update({3:4})
print data
```

which adds the same dictionary to your list, use this instead:

```
data = [{}, {}]
data[1].update({3:4})
print data
```

`data[1]` now means the second `{}` in your list. The result of this program is:

```
[{}, {3: 4}]
```

Why doesn't `data = [{}] * 2` work? Because it you are making the same thing twice, which means you are forced to replace both `{}` with `{3:4}` which gives you the result you had. With `data = [{}, {}]`, you can only change the second dictionary since `data[0]` is the first one and `data[1]` is the next item and so on.